# Arduino Mega & LIN Transceiver (MCP2004)

Tags: arduino, interface, pullup

I am trying to connect an [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560) with another device using a LIN Transceiver. I have decided to use a LIN [MCP2004 Transceiver](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002230E.pdf) for this.

I am now trying to understand the reference design of MCP2004.
I have come up with the following design but I have a couple of questions:

1. Should RxD be pulled up to 5 volt or 12 volt?
2. Are the values for R1 and R2 ok?
3. I don't understand what to do with the V_REN pin?

Thanks.

PS, please don't suggest other LIN transceivers since I only have access to MPC2004.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUpaF2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should RxD be pulled up to 5 volt or 12 volt?

To 5V, or else you're out of spec with with the Arduino.

> Are the values for R1 and R2 ok?

Looks alright. RXD is an open drain pin. It will connect the resistor from floating +5V to GND when active.

> I don't understand what to do with the V_REN pin?

My guess (from reading the datasheet) is that this circuit when used in an automotive application, is able to keep a connected MCU in reset/shutdown until the system voltage has stabilized. In the datasheet the circuit does this by using the V_REN pin connected to a voltage regulator that drives the connected MCU. The voltage regulator is implied to have a shutdown pin or similar that can be controlled by V_REN. The reason to do this is that the LIN bus should not be disturbed by stray data when the vehicle turns on and the MCU might be in a undefined state.

Comment: Hi and thanks, So it is okay to leave V_REN unconnected?

Comment: Yeah, you can leave it floating.

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic will keep the transceiver permanently awake, since CS will never go low. This may on may not be what you want. Most LIN designs are expected to go to sleep when the bus is not active in order to save power. If you don't plan to use WAKEUP frames, you don't need to implement sleep mode.

V_REN pin is related to sleep mode as well. The idea is to keep only the LIN transmitter powered during sleep, powering down the MCU. When a WAKEUP frame arrives, the V_REN pin will be driven high, powering up the MCU. In case of Arduino, you'll have to get rid of the bootloader if you want to use it in this mode, otherwise on wakeup it will be waiting for a programming sequence instead of reacting to the LIN messages.